# Need to bin all numeric variables with qcut in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and I need help.  I'm trying to bin all numeric variables (58) in a pandas dataframe with a For Loop, Pandas qcut function and list of variables.  However, I have two issues: 1) qcut is not returning the IDs included in the original dataframe.  I don't care about the original variables - I just need the new binned variables and the ID.  2nd) I can't get the For Loop to work.  See sample code (with two vars) below.
Many thanks to those that can help.
Ben

##SAMPLE CODE

#create sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
'totals1':[200, 100, 300, 500, 1000, 50, 250, 550, 350, 950],
'totals2':[4500, 700, 600, 500, 900, 500, 150, 650, 450, 950]})

df
```

#convert id as object

```
df = df.astype({'id' : np.object})

df.info()
```

#put the numeric variables in a list

```
num_vars = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.tolist()

num_vars
```

#loop through and bin each numvar.  ID needs to be included in final df.

```
for x in num_vars:
    
    #this works for the first num_var but I need the ID included 
    #    and to iterate through all numeric vars
    #df = pd.DataFrame(pd.qcut(df['totals1'], 3, labels=False))
    
    #this would be used in the For Loop but doesn't work
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.qcut(df[x], 3, labels=False))

#this may be more usefull since qcut just adds a column to the existing df.
df['Totals1_Seg'] = pd.DataFrame(pd.qcut(df['totals1'], 3, labels=False))
    
df
```

Comment: PS.  I don't need the cut ranges for each interval.  I just need the bins 1 - 3.  Thanks!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: a quick note.  it is considered poor practice to use a `for loop` in a dataframe. there are usually more efficient methods of iterating the data...

Comment: also,  what is "qcut". presumably a typo.  and what do you mean "bin all numeric variables".... delete them or put them into to discrete data bins ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The Pandas qcut function assigns bins or segments based on the value in the variable.  Here, I'm telling qcut the to create three segments and to assign the row either a 1, 2 or 3 based on the value...this is called binning, which is often used in segmentation and machine learning.  The QCUT function reviews all values and assigns the segment based on value ranges (0 to 300, 301 to 632, 633+, etc.), where each range is mutually exclusive of the others.  If a value falls in between 0 and 300 then it is assigned a 1.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output that matches the provided input?

Comment: The output would be ID then the columns with the binned values (1,2,3) for each.  Same column names as before...or they could be different.  So ID, Totals1, Totals2 or ID, Totals1binned, Totals2binned...something like that.  One word on QCUT, it dynamically determines the appropriate value ranges for each column then assigns the bin number (1,2,3) based on the range it came up with.  I made up the ranges in the example above.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant the explicit output for the example, as DataFrame

Comment: yes a dataframe but it will eventually be exported as CSV.

Comment: This will simply add a new binned column to the existing df...but how do you integrate it in a loop?                                                                                                     df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'totals1':[200, 100, 300, 500, 1000, 50, 250, 550, 350, 950],
                   'totals2':[4500, 700, 600, 500, 900, 500, 150, 650, 450, 950]})
df                                                                                                       
    df['Totals1_Seg'] = pd.DataFrame(pd.qcut(df['totals1'], 3, labels=False))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it to work but only when writing back to dataframe, which is a bad practice.   Any suggestions:

#create sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'totals1':[200, 100, 300, 500, 1000, 50, 250, 550, 350, 950],
                   'totals2':[450, 700, 600, 500, 900, 500, 150, 650, 450, 950]})
df
```

#convert id as object

```
df = df.astype({'id' : np.object})
df.info()
```

#put the numeric variables in a list

```
num_vars = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.tolist()
num_vars
```

#this for loop works but its also re-creating the df in every loop.

```
for x in num_vars:
    print(x)
    print(x.index(x)+1)
    df[x+'_Seg'] = pd.DataFrame(pd.qcut(df[x], 3, labels=False)+1)
    df = df.drop([x], axis = 1)
    
df
```